# Joomla - Why article URL SEF marging into menu SEF? I Need only menu SEF In my URL

Tags: php, url, joomla, sef

I have one article which name is **Landing page** page and it's Alias is **landing-page**
Select Category is **Uncategorised**.

then make menu with the name of MarshFarm and attached the article with menu

> MarshFarm (Alias: marshfarm)

when i assess the

> site.com/marshfarm

it auto redirect to

> site.com/marshfarm/uncategorised/landing-page

but i really need short URL like

> site.com/marshfarm

Please help me to solve the problem

Thanks